# Usage of 'éine' instead of 'eine'

Tags: spelling, history, diacritic

I'm reading "Der logische Aufbau der Welt" by Rudolf Carnap, which is quite an interesting book. But I found something I do not understand.

Everytime he writes the numeral "eine" or "ein" etc. he writes "éine" or "éin" etc.

Does anyone know why he does that? Is that an old spelling-rule that I as a native speaker am not aware of (which seems plausible, I'm not a professional linguist).

Here is one example:

[image]

This seems to happen all through out the book, so it's not a simple typo I guess.

Comment: Google Books also yields http://books.google.com.eg/books?id=tV8TAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA1-PA186&dq=%C3%A9ine&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6lnZUr7YFuGO0AW7k4D4BQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%C3%A9ine&f=false , which does the same.

Comment: Found out that it's used to denote the stressed syllable for german words in my linked book.

Answer (score 12):

I have also found the following quote from Carnap (bold face by me):

> Wie soll die Wissenschaft zu intersubjektiv gültigen Aussagen kommen, wenn alle ihre Gegenstände von **einem** individuellen Subjekt aus konstituiert werden, wenn also alle Aussagen der Wissenschaft im Grunde nur Beziehungen zwischen „meinen“ Erlebnissen zum Gegenstand haben? Da der Erlebnisstrom für jeden Menschen **ein** anderer ist, wie soll da auch nur **éin** Satz der Wissenschaft objektiv in diesem Sinne sein, d. h. für jedes Individuum gelten, wenn es von seine individuellen Erlebnisstrom ausgeht?

Taking this together with the three occurrence of *ein/éin* in your example, I hypothesise that *éin* marks the numeral one and *ein* marks the indefinite article (*a* in English). Let’s look at some examples:

> Wenn **ein** Konstitutionssystem der Begriffe oder der Gegenstände in der angedeuteten Art möglich ist, so folgt daraus […]

Here, the *wenn*-condition is fulfilled, if there is **a** *Konstitutionssystem* that fulfills the requirements. There may be many of those, it does not need to be exactly one.

> […] es gibt nur **éin** Gebiet von Gegenständen […]

Here he states that there is only **one** realm of items. It cannot be two or more; it is not indefinite in the sense that he refers to an arbitrary realm out of many possible (where you would use the indefinite article).

However, this is only a hypothesis based on six examples that needs to be tested by somebody who has access to the whole text.

---

In general, the double meaning of *ein* in German is hardly a problem, since it is most often clear from context which one is meant. However, I can imagine that this issue arises more often in philosophical texts.

Other ways to solve this disambiguity are to use:

> genau ein – exactly one (this is frequently used in mathematics)
>
> 1 (this is frequently used in board and card games, since it takes less space than *genau ein* and there is little space on cards)
>
> mindestens ein – at least one
>
> nur ein – only one

In spoken language the disambiguity can be avoided by emphasising the numeral *ein,* which is what might have inspired using an accent as a marker.

Comment: Thanks. This is a very interesting and logical approach. When continuing reading I will cast an eye on that. But I'm of course still open to answers by anyone else.

Comment: +1 and you can stop calling this a hypothesis. A stress mark marks stress by definition, in fact by its very name. Spanish does this, Russian does this, Greek does this, and while German typically does not do this, the atypical usage is nonetheless quite transparent. That being said, in Modern German it's far more common to use italics.

Comment: @RegDwight: While the aspect of stress or emphasis is another relevant angle to this phenomenon, I would not jump to conclusions for the following reasons: 1) This is the very first time I saw something like this. 2) If Carnap actually were using this as a stress mark, why does he not use it on stressed words other than *ein?* 3) The numeral *ein* is not always stressed. Though it may be stressed in all the available examples, there may be other examples where the *éin* is used for the numeral, but not stressed – if yes, the acute does not mark stress here; if no, my hypothesis is wrong.

Comment: The first occurence of your additional quote is an `ein` without acute ("von einem individuellen Subject"). From my point of view, this should denote the numeral and consequently be `éin` instead. So maybe, it's just emphasis, which helps to differentiate indefinite article and numeral.

Comment: @Toscho: I disagree: As I understand it, the sentence states that there is one individual *Subjekt* per *Gegenstand* – some of them may be identical, but not all of them. If the numeral *(éin)* were used here, it would mean that there is only one *Subjekt* in general, from which all *Gegenstände* are constructed.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft The following clause speaks of "'meine' Erlebnisse" which indicates to me, that it is indeed one and only one person ("Subjekt") for all the objekts ("Gegenstände"). The text is just about, that all these constructions are valid only to one person.

Comment: @Toscho: You are most probably right and I misinterpreted the sentence. However, I still think that the indefinite article *ein* could be used here though the numeral *ein* would do as well. When translating into English, e.g., both, *one* and *a,* make sense to me here.